# Make program invisible in other Workspaces

Tags: gnome, kde, ubuntu-unity

I am looking on how to move a program (eg. firefox, or a PDf Viewer) to a workspace, without being displayed in the program bar (KDE default bottom, Ubuntu-Unitiy default left) of the other workspaces. I need that for both KDE & Ubuntu Unity, but for completeness let' say also for Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to put the program to tray using e.g. `alltray`, and then hide it tray icon.